# How to evaluate and plot first and second differentials of dependent variables after solving system of DE using NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation

```
Y[t_] = {Y1[t], Y2[t]};
Fyd = {Y1[t] (Y2[t] - 1),  Y2[t] (2 - Y1[t])};
system = Thread[D[Y[t], t] == Fyd];
Ins = {Y1[0] == 1, Y2[0] == 1};
lvs = Join[system, Ins];
lvd = NDSolve[lvs, Y[t], {t, 0, 25}];
```

Now I want to plot the differentials of variables as

```
 Plot[Evaluate[{D[Y[t], t]} /. {lvd}], {t, 0, 25}]
```

But this step is not able to produce the plot.
Please suggest how can I plot or evaluate
(code is intentionally written in the vector form)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the line `lvd=...` of your code to

```
lvd = NDSolve[lvs, {Y1, Y2}, {t, 0, 25}]
```

you can plot the vectorlist

```
Plot[Y'[t] /. lvd, {t, 0, 25}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please elaborate the difference?

Comment: ??? `Plot[Y1'[t]-Y2'[t] /. lvd, {t, 0, 25}] `???

Comment: @Sairam, when you specify `Y[t]`,  you get a replacement rule for explicitly `Y[t]`. Whereas when you ask for `Y`, you get a `Function` object, that can figure out how to take the derivative.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann :  difference between using lvd = NDSolve[lvs, {Y1, Y2}, {t, 0, 25}]  instead of lvd = NDSolve[lvs, Y[t], {t, 0, 25}].

Comment: @Sairam: `NDSolve[lvs, Y[t], {t, 0, 25}]` returns InterpolationFunctions `{Y1[t]->..,Y2[t]->..}` which you have to differentiate later. In contrast `NDSolve[lvs, {Y1, Y2}, {t, 0, 25}]` returns a result which can be substituted directly into differential equations